# for loop and if statements in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am a biologist that is starting to have to learn some elementary scripting skills to deal with large DNA sequence data sets. So please go easy on me. I am doing this all in bash. I have a file with my data formatted like this:

```
CLocus_58919_Sample_25_Locus_33235_Allele_0
TGCAGGTGCTTCCAGTTGTCTTTGTAGCGTCCCACCATGATCTGCAGGTCCTTG
CLocus_58919_Sample_9_Locus_54109_Allele_0
TGCAGGTGCTTCCAGTTGTCTTTGTAGCGTCCCACCATGATCTGCAGGTCCTTG
```

What I need is to do is loop through this file and write all the sequences from the same sample into their own file. Just to be clear, these sequences come from samples 25 and 9. So my idea was to use awk to reformat my file in the following way:

```
CLocus_58919_Sample_25_Locus_33235_Allele_0_TGCAGGTGCTTCCAGTTGTCTTTGTAGCGTCCCACCATGATCTGCAGGTCCTTG
CLocus_58919_Sample_9_Locus_54109_Allele_0_TGCAGGTGCTTCCAGTTGTCTTTGTAGCGTCCCACCATGATCTGCAGGTCCTTG
```

then pipe this into another awk if statement to say "if sample=$i then write out that entire line to a file named sample.$i" Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`ls /scratch/tkchafin/data/raw | wc -l`;
b=1;
c=$((a-b));

mkdir /scratch/tkchafin/data/phylogenetics

for ((i=0; i<=$((c)); i++)); do
    awk 'ORS=NR%2?"_":"\n"' $1 |  awk -F_ '{if($4==$i) print}' >> /scratch/tkchafin/data/phylogenetics/sample.$i
done;
```

I understand this is not working because `$i` is in single quotes so bash is not recognizing it. I know `awk` has a `-v` option for passing external variables to it, but I don't know how I would apply that in this case. I tried to move the `for` loop inside the `awk` statement but this does not produce the desired result either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do have limited experience using perl. The problem is the rest of my very large pipeline is already written in bash.

Comment: I know the learning curve might seem more daunting, but this is a problem that's very suited to perl string parsing. You would read through the lines and collect the data you need into hashs of arrays of strings  e.g. 
$sample{
   'CLocus_58919_Sample_25' => 
        {
        'Locus_33235_Allele_0' => 'TGCAGGTGCTTCCAGTTGTCTTTGTAGCGTCCCACCATGATCTGCAGGTCCTTG',
        'some other locaus amd allel' =>'DNA sequence'
        }
    }
Once that's done traversing and writing to file/files would be relatively easy

Comment: the previouse comment really didnt come out the way i wanted, sorry. 

You can still use the bash scripts you have. just invoke a perl script for this portion of it.

Comment: @UriMikhli This is really simple enough for awk, see my answer.

Comment: @Barmar Cool. Yeah, that would work. 
It's been a very long time since I've written with awk and sed. I tend to naturally gravitate towards perl because it's more lexically human readable.
 A big problem for me used to be looking at a large awk sript I'd written, say a few months before and scratching my head in confusion until I was able to insert my mind back into the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `awk` write directly to the desired output file, without a shell loop:

```
awk -F_ '(NR % 2) == 1 { line1 = $0; fn="/scratch/tkchafin/data/phylogenetics/sample."$4; }
         (NR % 2) == 0 { print line1"_"$0 > fn; }' "$1"
```

But to show how you would use `-v` in your version, it would be:

```
for ((i=0; i<=$((c)); i++)); do
    awk 'ORS=NR%2?"_":"\n"' $1 |  awk -F_ -v i=$i '$4 == i' >> /scratch/tkchafin/data/phylogenetics/sample.$i
done;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This does exactly what I needed it to. I thought I had tried this very thing, but obviously not.